# Angular 8 - How to resolve 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError'

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a component that uploads files to a database. Whilst the files are uploading I display an overlay with the amount of files selected, and the amount of files successfully uploaded.

I wanted the overlay to automatically close when the amount of files uploaded is equal to the amount of files selected. However, my implementation has resulted in the following:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'

When files are selected for upload, I set `overlay_uploadImage` to `true`. That will display the overlay. Inside the overlay I have the following div. My intention here was that when the upload count is equal to the amount of files selected for upload, then call the `overlay_uploadImage` function. This function will set `overlay_uploadImage` to `false` and therefore hide the overlay container.

```
 <div *ngIf="uploadCount == files.length?overlay_uploadImage:false"></div>
```

**Function called when criteria is met**

```
overlay_imageUploads(){
    this.files = [];
    this.overlay_uploadImage = false;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what the negative vote was for? (for whoever that is...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes when angular  checks a value and then the value changes, its not an "error" as it doesnt breaks

I suggest you to use a different syntax:

```
 <div *ngIf="overlay_UploadImage  && uploadCount === files.length"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great elegant solution. The only change is that it would be `uploadCount !== files.length` - That way when the overlay is true and the uploadCount hasn't reached the total selected files, the overlay will display. When the uploadCount is matching to the total files, it hides! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually ask angular to detect changes to get rid of this error:

```js
import {ChangeDetectorRef} for '@angular/core';
[...]
    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

    [...]

    overlay_imageUploads(){
        this.files = [];
        this.overlay_uploadImage = false;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This results in `Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges`

Comment: Ok, probably because it's trying to check the element which now has `*ngIf="false"` so doesn't exist, you can try changing your detection startegy to onPuch on your component but beware of side-effects^^

Answer (score 0):

```
    constructor( private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef )

    overlay_imageUploads(){
    if (!(this.changeDetect as ViewRef).destroyed) {
          this.changeDetect.detectChanges()
          // do other tasks
          this.files = [];
          this.overlay_uploadImage = false;
      }
    }
```

This code will force to change value.

see references here: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Thanks for the response, this results in `Maximum call stack size exceeded`